# Promo Page - Meta Suggestion

Tags: discussion, publicity

Inspired by this post [How would having the writing challenges on Meta work out?](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/how-would-having-the-writing-challenges-on-meta-work-out/1886#1886) , I've been wondering if Meta can be used to promote people's works.

One of my friends (writes a lot of tie-in novels mostly, and a few independent fantasy series) every month has an "irons in the fire" post (about his ongoing projects, upcoming con appearances) AND a "Buy my Stuff" post - where he links to his active/ongoing columns, and a list of completed works.

"Irons in the Fire" seems a little chaotic for so many of us, but if any of us have *published* works, ongoing columns or podcasts, an essay in an anthology, complete books (whether traditionally or self-published), it would be cool to let the rest of us know.  Maybe we have some more pros here than we know?

*I am not volunteering to run this.*

**I am thinking that a Quarterly Post with a community edit answer** (like the current question-drive contest) would be a good way to let us promo our work, advertise ourselves WITHIN writing.SE as having some authority, and build a sense of community.

(I'd *like* to track down everyone's profile, and then go to their webpage as listed, and from there....  But I'm not as likely to do so.  And I may miss something I'd love because I never noticed their answers because they were about a different area of writing.  Or they've only asked 1 or 2 questions.)

By having it quarterly, as people fade in and out of writing.SE, only those actively involved in the site would be listed (but the archived ones would be there for those curious about our prior contributors.)

Proposed answer format:
User Name - Writer Name (if different) - Work Type - Name of Work - Relevant Link - one line summary.

for "Type" I mean Novel, column, podcast, (guest column, guest on podcast), something in anthology...  So someone with a *recurring* blog post would just have:

> - SE-Scully - Dana NotScully - Column on GeekHaus- X-Files Monster Rewatch - link to it - personal column  covering every episode that doesn't include the big mythology.

(Instead of listing all 12 posts in that topic for the quarter.)

But if someone is just guest-writing one article, or guested on some podcasts as a rare thing, then they can link to those unique instances.

I'm just throwing this idea out there while I procrastinate my tech-writing dayjob stuff. (and heck, if people want to "promo" that they wrote a private user guide or proposal for work, they can list that, just so we consolidate a list of some expertise, even if no one can access/buy said documentation.)

Thoughts? Has this been tried before and failed? Besides the post listed above, I am sorta inspired by the worldbuilding.SE "question Sandbox" where every answer is a question to workshop before posting it, and then periodically the topic is closed and restarted.  So perhaps individual answers may be the way to go instead of a consolidated community answer.

Comment: Like this? https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1364/1993  (Obviously not very prominent right now, but is that the sort of thing you had in mind?)

Comment: Exactly!  and to answer your question from below, yes, I was thinking Meta can also = community, like the writing-prompts thing that inspired my question.

Answer (score 3):

## RPG uses a chat-bot for this

Over on RPG.SE we have a chat bot that posts new things from various blogs and RSS feeds. [These feeds are voted on by the community](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3041/rpg-general-chat-vote-for-your-feeds) to decide how useful they are. Highly voted answers get added to the chat bot.

Some of the feeds are the personal blogs of users as well as popular resources and news. It is a good way to promote users work but also keep the main site and meta clear of clutter.

With a smaller user base and significantly less active chat I'm not sure how this would work here. Perhaps it could be the impetus to increase chat participation?

Answer (score 2):

I would argue for a no.

Meta is for discussing the site itself (including topicality and policy), and for discussing the software that the site runs on (including reporting bugs or asking for help with a feature).

Meta is not for promotion of off-site works, whether published on dead trees or recycled electrons.

Meta is also not, as I've seen examples of from time to time in various places on the network, for "stuff that's off topic on the main site".

I can understand the value of promoting one's work. However, Q&A is not the place for that. You'd also need to consider the audience; is fellow writers really the appropriate target demographic for your work?

Compare the section on advertising in [Expected Behavior](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and [How to not be a spammer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), both in the help center, respectively.

Comment: There is also room on individual profiles for self-promotion. although clearly not the same thing as what the question asks for.

Comment: @bruglesco Indeed; in general, the user has quite a bit of latitude in what they can put into their own profile. Putting in a link to "here are the books I have published" would almost certainly be fine, *especially* if the user is a positive contributor in other ways.

Comment: Meta can also be about the community, if managed carefully so it doesn't go wild.  For example, Worldbuilding has a meta post with links to all blog posts; the blog is unofficial but by and largely for the community.  Actually, don't we have a "what have you published?" post here already?  (Goes to look.)